# No free space to select when trying to make a new partition at install time

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to make some free space on my disk into a new partition, but the Ubuntu installer doesn't see the free space. I booted Windows and checked that there was space available and there was.

[image: screenshot of partition editor]

Comment: Are you using `gparted`? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: sure just wait a minute

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/DQNOG93 here it is as you can see there is no free space option

Comment: sorry for the delay

Comment: It is not `gparted` screenshot. Most likely you created an empty ntfs partition in Windows.

Comment: You may have created one or two extra ntfs partitions from windows. If you have done that, boot Windows again and delete the new ntfs partition(s). You need to keep that space **unallocated**. If you haven't created any new ntfs partitions, then your computer came with 4 partitions. If your computer has old type BIOS (not UEFI) and the hard disk has MBR instead of GPT, then you will need to delete one of the four partitions. Edit your question again with information about [MBR or GPT](https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/)

Answer (score 2):

Hope these steps help you resolve your issue:

1. Boot into your Windows system and right-click on the Start Menu >> Command Line (Admin) to enter into the Windows command-line interface.
2. Once you enter into the command-line interface, type `diskmgmt.msc` on the promt to enter into **Disk Management** utility. From here, check if you have any unallocated space on your disk. If not, right click on **C:** partition and select **Shrink Volume** in order to resize the partition.
3. Enter a particular value (as per your requirement) and select **Shrink** to resize the partition to that specific size. We would now be using this new unallocated space to install Ubuntu.

Before you proceed with the next section to install Ubuntu, ensure you create a bootable USB device using either Rufus or Universal USB Installer. Once you have a bootable media handy with you, follow the link to [dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/).

P.S. While installation, choosing **Install alongside Windows boot manager** is safe, but please follow the guide properly else you might mess your hard disk permanently.

Also, creating a Swap partition is recommended. Having a Swap partition will not impact your working.

Once you have installed the Ubuntu on your system, the next step would be to include GRUB on your boot. To do so, follow the below steps:

- Boot into Windows OS
- Combine  <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys together and type `cmd` to open the command prompt.
  (You do not require any admin rights to execute the below command)
- Once you are in command prompt window, type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` on the prompt and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

As soon as the command gets executed, reboot your system and then you will always find options to pick either `Ubuntu` or `Windows` as your preferred OS.